# error: ‘Page’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I have the following c++ classes:

Page.h:

```
#ifndef PAGE_H_
#define PAGE_H_

#include "Process.h"

class Page {
public:
    Page();
    virtual ~Page();
    Process *process;
};

#endif /* PAGE_H_ */
```

and Process.h:

```
#ifndef PROCESS_H_
#define PROCESS_H_

#include <vector>
#include "Page.h"

class Process {
public:
    Process();
    virtual ~Process();

    int size;
    double life_remaining;
    std::vector<Page> pages;
};

#endif /* PROCESS_H_ */
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
../src/Process.h:21:14: error: ‘Page’ was not declared in this scope
../src/Process.h:21:18: error: template argument 1 is invalid
../src/Process.h:21:18: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

How do I correct this? 
When I comment out the lines: #include "Proccess.h" and Process *process; then it compiles. When I remove the comments it gives me the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a forward declaration instead of inclusion in `Page.h`:

```
//replace this:
//#include "Process.h"

//with this:
class Process;

class Page {
public:
    Page();
    virtual ~Page();
    Process *process;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a [*circular dependency*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) between `Process` and `Page`.

Instead of...

```
#include "Process.h"
```

...in Page.h , forward declare...

```
class Process;
```

...and this will allow you to have `Process* process;` in your `Page` `class`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Process.h is first included in Page.h rather than Page.h in Process.h.